# get one object in queryset iteration

Tags: python, django

I have two models, A and B, and B is ForienKey relationship to A.

I want to check each object in queryset and if it has certain fields then I want to display it in template.

Below is my template example:

```
{% for a in a_qs %}
<tr>
  <th>{{ a.b_set.first.a_field }}</th>
  <th>{{ a.b_set.first.another_field }}</th>
{% endfor %}
```

They work fine, but I want to apply something like `get` method in queryset. Below is what I want to achieve:

```
{% for a in a_qs %}
<tr>
  <th>{{ a.b_set.get(a_field_in_B='hello').a_field }}</th>
  <th>{{ a.b_set.get(a_field_in_B='hello').another_field }}</th>
{% endfor %}
```

I understand that something above is not possible and I want to give some change to my `views` or `models`, but I don't know where to start.

Below is something like my views.py snippet:

```
a_qs = A.objects.all()
a_obj = a.b_set.get(a_field='something') # a is not defined yet. I want every a in a_qs to be checked
```

Thanks for your advice in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django templates are deliberately restricted to not allow method calls with parameters, as well as subscripts, etc. The reason is that *business logic* does not belong in the templates, but in the views.

You can make use of a [**`Prefetch`** object [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Prefetch) to load objects per item. This will normally be faster as well, since all the related objects are loaded in bulk:

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch

a_qs = A.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch(
    'b_set',
    B.objects.filter(a_field='something'),
    'b_filtered'
))
```

If you pass this to the template, you can render this with:

```
{% for a in a_qs %}
<tr>
  <th>{{ a.b_filtered.0.a_field }}</th>
  <th>{{ a.b_filtered.0.another_field }}</th>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

or more elegant:

```
{% for a in a_qs %}
<tr>
  {% with b_first=a.b_filtered.0 %}
  <th>{{ b_first.a_field }}</th>
  <th>{{ b_first.another_field }}</th>
  {% endwith %}
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. What if I want to have another field to lookup in `b_set`? Could you shed a light on it please?

Comment: @harryghgim: you can add an extra `Prefetch` object, that you of course give another name than `b_filtered` (for example `b_filtered2`).